# trying to load a json data with getJson in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to load some data from my Json file with jquery, but I'm not sure, why it wont work! I'm also trying to sort and find a specific object in the array in the Json file. Here is some of my code :

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = 'content.json';
    var outp = {
                    low         :   0,
                    high        :   99,
                    name        :   "Fritz",
                    rufnummer   :   "012",
                    faxnummer   :   "345",
                    mobil       :   "678",
                    mail        :   "mail@mail.mail",  
                }

    var searchplz = parseInt(.inp.toString().substr(0,2));

    $(.find).click(function(){
        $.getJSON(url,data,function(data,status)){
            if(status === 200 && .inp.length == 5){
                if(searchplz != 85){
                    for (var i = data.PLZ.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if(data.PLZ[i].low <= searchplz && data.PLZ[i].high >= searchplz){
                            outp = data.PLZ[i];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    searchplz = parseInt(.inp.toString().substr(0,3));
                    if (searchplz == 850 || searchplz == 851){
                        outp = data.PLZ[21];
                    } else {
                        outp = data.PLZ[22];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Postleitszahl:</p>
    <input type="number" autocomplete="on" name="inp" class="inp">
    <button type="button" class="find">Finden</button>
    <p class="output"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a typo, your click event certainly dont trigger:

```
$(.find).click
```

should be

```
$('.find').click
```

Also, the `data` parameter doesn't exists (at least in the code you show us)

```
$.getJSON(url,data,
```

***EDIT :***

There is another problem in your code. You use `.inp` as a variable, when it's only a CSS class.

You can't do

```
var searchplz = parseInt(.inp.toString().substr(0,2));
```

The `.inp.toString()` part is wrong. You need to use jquery to get the DOM element with the class `.inp`, then you'll be able to use its value :

```
var inp = $(".inp").val();
```

Here you get the input with class `.inp`, and assign its value to the variable `inp`. `inp` is now a string.

You can now use the `var inp` like this :

```
var searchplz = parseInt(inp.substr(0,2));
```

Report this modification in your whole code.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I commented out everything in the script besides the click and fixed the '.find' and added a console.log('test'); to see if it triggers and it doesnt, any clue why that is?

Comment: I completed my answer. Tell me if it's enough

Comment: Yesterday I scratched my code because I made little errors I couldnt identify and started over today. I found out that my main problem was, that i didnt wait for the page to load first with $(document).ready( function() { }); ! But anyway thanks for the info that i have to transform my class value into a var first to use it. now I used your suggestion for my new code and it works awesomely! Thanks so much for your efford!

Comment: I had the same problem of forgeting a parameter. Stupid of me and thanks to you.